# Cannot print to console

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to angular and trying to implement a reactive form. Below is my html code and TS code

```html
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up</div>
</form>
```

Here is my TS file

```
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent    implements OnInit{
  title = 'app works!';
  signupForm : FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.signupForm =  new FormGroup({
      'email' : new FormControl('test@test.com')

    });

    // this.signupForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
    //   (value) => console.log(value)
    // );
  }


  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.signupForm);
  }

}
```

For some reason I cannot print anything on console which I  am trying to do in OnSubmit method. I checked everything and it looked okay , but still nothing comes on console when I press the button. 
Can anyone please help me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: replace   <div class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up</div>
by   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up</button>

Comment: Thanks!! Cannot mark comment at answer. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute type is not a valid type on div element. This this case you will need to have an input or button with type submit for the callback to be triggered.

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Mail</label>
             <input type="email"
                 name="email"
                 id="email"
                 formControlName="email"
                 class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```